# Button does not appear in my layout

Tags: android, android-layout

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    style="@style/listbag">
     <LinearLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/groupListView"
        style="@style/listbag"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector1"
        android:background="@drawable/radius"  />
 </LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addfrendstogroupButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:text="Create new group" 
        android:textColor="@color/gray2"
        android:background="@drawable/button_indicator"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        />
       </RelativeLayout>

          </LinearLayout>
```

I want to set listview and in the bottom of the screen one button. But when I fill listView the button not appear any more. I don't know why. Could anyone help me here?

Comment: What do you mean by "filling the ListView" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your listview and button be in a **single relative layout**. And give your button the property of `alignparentbottom`. The button will always be above the list even if your listview is full and needs scrolling.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make your layout looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    <ListView>
        ....
    </ListView>
    <Button
        ....
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        .... />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to @iturki that it would be more flexible to do it like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<Button
    ....
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    .... />
<ListView>
    ....
    android:above="@id/button"
    ....
</ListView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Otherwise the `Button` will go on top of the ListView and therefore hiding the end of it.

Comment: i think that is what is wanted, for the button to be over the list incase its full.

Comment: SWhat I meant is that with the other answer the `Button` would hide the end of the `ListView`. **Updated**

Comment: <RelativeLayout  ==>  this is correct. without  '>'  for very beginners like me..

Comment: This answer is from 2011, now it's 2020 and no one should use RelativeLayout. Go with ConstraintsLayout if you are trying something like this :)